# Enable static for django-tinymce when using amazon-s3

Tags: django, amazon-s3, django-tinymce

The website on Django 1.10.
Can't understand the work TinyMCE.
The site statics are located on AWS S3.

**settings.py**

```
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = os.environ.get('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID')
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = os.environ.get('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY')
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = 'orpro-assets'                                
AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN = 
'{}.s3.amazonaws.com'.format(AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME)
AWS_S3_OBJECT_PARAMETERS = {'CacheControl': 'max-age=86400',}
REGION_NAME = 'us-east-1'
AWS_LOCATION = 'static'
AWS_MEDIA = 'media'
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto3.S3Boto3Storage'
STATIC_URL = "https://{}/{}/".format(AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN, 
AWS_LOCATION)
AWS_PUBLIC_MEDIA_LOCATION = 'media'
MEDIA_URL = "https://{}/{}/".format(AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN, AWS_MEDIA)
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'app.storage_backends.MediaStorage'

TINYMCE_DEFAULT_CONFIG = {
    'theme': "lightgray",
    'relative_urls': False}
TINYMCE_JS_ROOT = STATIC_URL + 'tiny_mce'
TINYMCE_JS_URL = STATIC_URL + 'tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js'
TINYMCE_INCLUDE_JQUERY = False
```

**storage_backends.py**

```
from storages.backends.s3boto3 import S3Boto3Storage

class MediaStorage(S3Boto3Storage):
    location = 'media'
    file_overwrite = False
```

When you load the home page, at the end of the load appears scripts that link to the folder `static` site.
There are no such scripts in the templates. 
But the addition of the block is enabled:
    `{% block additional_scripts %}`
    `{% endblock %}`

All other static files are loaded correctly with amazon-s3

**Update**
The site is launched in the mode `DEBUG = False`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have 'tinymce' in your INSTALLED_APPS in your settings file.

Once this is done, run `python manage.py collectstatic`

Comment: I run `collectstatic`, and `tinymce` in my `INSTALLED_APPS`